# Coefficient of $x^2$ in the polynomial

Tags: polynomials

How to find the coefficient of $x^2$ in the polynomial
$$(1-x)(1+2x)(1-3x)....(1+14x)(1-15x)$$

Is there any particular way to look at such problems?

Comment: Factorize your polynomial by $15!$ and use [those formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: The roots are already given so you may look at the patterns on the relationships of roots of a polynomial and the coefficients of the expanded form of the polynomial. Try first at the quadratic and cubic cases. Then you can generalize the pattern

Comment: Since it is the 12th time you post here, you already know that you should provide more context and your attempts. Otherwise, you question is likely to be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

The terms $x^2$ appear as the product of $x$'s from two factors, while the $1$'s are used from the remaining factors.

Hence taking all pairs of factors,

$$C_2=\sum_{i=1}^{14}\sum_{j=i+1}^{15}(-1)^ii(-1)^jj.$$

You can ease this computation by taking all pairs twice, including the diagonal ones and

$$2C_2=\sum_{i=1}^{15}\sum_{j=1}^{15}(-1)^ii(-1)^jj-\sum_{i=1}^{15}((-1)^ii)^2\\
=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{15}(-1)^ii\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{15}i^2\\
=8^2-1240.$$

Answer (score -1):

Since the constant term in each binomial factor is $1$, then we can express the coefficient of the $x^2$ term as the sum of the following series:

$-2+3-4+5-6+7...+15$

$-2-6+8-10+12-14...-30$

$...$

$15-30+45-60+75-90...-210$

The sum of all these sums is the answer, because for each factor, you're multiplying the $x$ term with the $x$ term from another factor and then just multiplying by the $1$ for the rest of terms to yield a $x^2$ term.